# Mysql not all arguments converted during string formatting using python

Tags: insert, typeerror

Under a database, I am currently creating several tables and inserting several cvs files into these tables.

While I succeeded in inserting some CVS files, some files I failed.

The code I failed is as below

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/leigh/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
import mysql.connector
import config
import csv
import os

dbcon = mysql.connector.connect(database=config.db, user=config.user, password=config.passwd, host=config.host)
dbcur = dbcon.cursor()
dbcur.execute('CREATE TABLE parking (Place_ID int, Parking varchar(50))')

with open('/Users/leigh/documents/RCdata/chefmozparking.csv') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
  next(reader, None)
  for row in reader:
    dbcur.execute('INSERT INTO parking (Place_ID, Parking) VALUES(%s, "%s")' % tuple(row))

dbcon.commit()
```

I used the same format (same code function on another datasets with same data structure) on the succeeded ones, but this one just failed with the error written:

**dbcur.execute('INSERT INTO parking (Place_ID, Parking) VALUES(%s, "%s")' % tuple(row))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting**

The columns are perfectly matched and the data type cannot be wrong.
I am not very experienced in MySQL, and I have looked through the internet and still cannot find what is wrong here.
Could some one please kindly tell me what is going on?
Thanks!

// If further information is needed, please just let me know.